# Error "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am developing a web application project using asp.net, c#, and SQL server. The uploading process is working perfectly however downloading process got this error "Input string was not in a correct format". the column class_id in the table is varchar and i use it as DataKeyNames in the gridview

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("class_id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

the following code is used to download file when the download button which is in gridview clicked

```
 protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int class_id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument); // the error is here
        byte[] bytes;
        string fileName, contentType;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())//Error is here
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["filePath"];
                    contentType = sdr["fileType"].ToString();
                    fileName = sdr["fileName"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

how can this error be solved.
thanks in advance

Comment: Which line gives this error? Fun though it might be too guess its probably easiest for you to tell us.

Comment: have you set a breakpoint at that line to check what if any value is being sent in the CommandArgument property of the sender object?

Comment: `WHERE [class_id] + [module_id] LIKE '%" + para.Text.Trim() + "%'`? This is causing your issue, but you should not concatenate strings to create the sql string at all. Instead use parameters.

Comment: sorry, this code is corrected so it used to search the file details. i just removed from [Lecturer]

Comment: yes i did beakpoint and the class_is is displayed in string format.. and the error in this line  int class_id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);

Comment: it is not null, it takes the class_id which is in string format like "uc3f13se"

Comment: You cannot parse uc3f13se to an int. Int is an integer.

Comment: Also doing (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument is a bad way to do that. the as keyword will return null if it fails to cast. If you know for a fact that should be a LinkButton you should do it this way, ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument, this way you will get a Casting Error instead of a null reference error if it fails to cast.

Comment: how can i pass the class_id in string format using ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value that is coming from the command is something like "uc3f13se". Then you are trying to parse it into an integer. That value is not an integer so the int.Parse() will fail.

```
int class_id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
```

You should probably just use it as a string, CommandArgument is most likely a string type already given the example value you gave me:

```
var class_id = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
```

This is assuming of course if your class_id column in your db is a varchar or some other string accepting type.

If you have more questions about int.Parse() you can visit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx), this has what kinds of exceptions it throws and how you cause them.

Comment: it works but now i got this error ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized in the same code

Comment: cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["filePath"];
                    contentType = sdr["fileType"].ToString();
                    fileName = sdr["fileName"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();

Comment: That seems like a new question. The answer I provided answered your original question.  I would suggest marking this one as the answer and then trying to figure out the next part. If it continues to fail post a new question.

Comment: I do have an idea of what your problem is, you are creating a command that is not associated with SqlConnection you are generating. The hint here is that SqlCommand object has a CreateCommand method.

Start here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

SqlCommand command= connection.CreateCommand();

Comment: `SELECT [class_id], [module_id], [lecturer_id], [type], [start_date], [end_date], [name], [filePath] FROM [Lecturer] FROM [ClassAssignmentModule]";` why are there 2 FROM statements?

Comment: Good call totally missed that.

Comment: why are you calling ` GridView1.DataBind();` before you even have any data to bind to.. this is by far the sloppiest code I've ever seen

Comment: Well honestly this looks like homework. It's probably a student just getting into coding. So sloppy is expected. :)

Comment: `sdr.Read();` how about using a While loop to read also check to see if there is anything to read / being returned it's got `ERRORS` written all over this mess should read as follows for starters 
`while (sdr.Read()){ }` then try to populate the values

Comment: take look to the code now after edited, this the original code and the lines that i removed from the code not used to do anything like  DataBind or select command...

Comment: Cubicle it is not homework as you said.. i just thought you will look to the problem where i mention it not to the whole code.. thanks

Comment: Like I suggested you probably should have asked as a new question. Now that the code was modified after an answer was given and selected it looks weird and it hard to follow.  I will be happy to go over to the new question if you post it.

Comment: Thank you @Cubicle.Jockey, your answer was perfect ... thanks again now the project is working perfectly :)